# How to update the value of json by reading path in java?

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to update "$.widget.debug" value. 
Using which library I can do this. I tried many libraries but unable to do this.

```
{
    "widget": {
        "debug": "on",
        "window": {
            "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
            "name": "main_window",
            "width": 500,
            "height": 500
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, can you post the Java code you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JsonFlattener library which will flatten the json.
After flattening it will be like this.

```
{
    "widget.debug": "on",
    "widget.window.title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
    "widget.window.name": "main_window",
    "widget.window.width": 500,
    "widget.window.height": 500
}
```